# How can I use a JavaScript file in my ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to use a JavaScript file, lying in the root folder. How can I include that JS file?

Comment: Use "JavaScript" or "Javascript" or even "javascript." JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript and *has nothing to do with Java*.

Comment: Or even "JS" would do. And JScript is another story...

Comment: How do you not know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be the same as including it in any standard html page..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scriptname.js"></script>
```

If this isn't exactly what you are looking for let me know and I'd be happy to expand as far as I can.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<script language="javascript" src="FILE PATH"></script>
```

Comment: The standard way is to use type="text/javascript" instead of the language attribute.

Comment: Actually `language` attribute is used for old browser compatibility but the current modern browsers is now using `type="text/javascript"`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to include the JavaScript from the code behind of a page or WebControl, you have a few options

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(WebControlThatNeedsIt), "IdentifierOfTheScriptSuchAsLoad", "~/myfile.js");

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(WebControlThatNeedsIt), "IdentifierOfTheScriptSuchAsLoad", "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/myfile.js\"></script>",false);
```

If not you can use what Quinton Suggested in the markup.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myfile.js"></script>
```

Note that using the

```
</script>
```

is important, as self closing doesn't work with script tags i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myfilewontwork.js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using Visual Studio, you can drag the file right into your aspx file and it will generate the correct markup for you.